# Pandas JSON type to Flat File Output

Tags: python, pandas

I have the df in the following format -

Customer, the product they buy, and the frequency of their buy.
For this example, I have named the product as product1, product2 etc.
Also, there are about 150 products and they are not relevant to all customers.
Like how it is showed in the dataset below -

```
customer    buys
customer1   {"product1":2, "product2":3, "product7":5, "product10":1, "product12":2, "product3":10}
customer2   {"product10":2, "product11":3, "product17":5, "product1":1}
customer3   {"product20":5, "product12":8, "product3":9, "product11":2}
```

Looking to convert this to the following format -

```
          product1 product2  product3   ..
customer1   2        3         10   ..
customer2   1        0         0    ..
customer3   0        0         9    ..
```

This will allow me to run models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your buys column is of dictionary format, you can apply `pd.Series` to it:

I have shown the steps below

```
>>> df.buys.apply(pd.Series)
   product1  product2  product7  product10  product12  product3  product11  product17  product20
0       2.0       3.0       5.0        1.0        2.0      10.0        NaN        NaN        NaN
1       1.0       NaN       NaN        2.0        NaN       NaN        3.0        5.0        NaN
2       NaN       NaN       NaN        NaN        8.0       9.0        2.0        NaN        5.0
>>> df.buys.apply(pd.Series).fillna(0)
   product1  product2  product7  product10  product12  product3  product11  product17  product20
0       2.0       3.0       5.0        1.0        2.0      10.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
1       1.0       0.0       0.0        2.0        0.0       0.0        3.0        5.0        0.0
2       0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        8.0       9.0        2.0        0.0        5.0
>>> out = pd.concat([df.customer, df.buys.apply(pd.Series).fillna(0)], axis=1)
>>> out
    customer  product1  product2  product7  product10  product12  product3  product11  product17  product20
0  customer1       2.0       3.0       5.0        1.0        2.0      10.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
1  customer2       1.0       0.0       0.0        2.0        0.0       0.0        3.0        5.0        0.0
2  customer3       0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        8.0       9.0        2.0        0.0        5.0
```

Comment: df.buys.apply(pd.Series) appears not to work.

Comment: @Santoo This should work. What output are you getting when doing above?

Comment: I added an answer as to why it might not be working..

Comment: @Ank Thank you so much for your help. It works perfect now.

Comment: @crayxt Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition on **@crayxt**'s brilliant answer, if that solution does not work, check the type of your values in **buys** column first. If it is `str` type, then you have those dictionaries stored as string values in your df:

```
>>> type(df.buys.iloc[0])
<class 'str'>
```

In that case, do below first to convert the string values to dictionaries:

```
>>> df['buys'] = df['buys'].apply(eval)
>>>
>>> type(df.buys.iloc[0])
<class 'dict'>
```

Now **buys** column contains `dict` values, so you can proceed with the recommended solution:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df.customer, df.buys.apply(pd.Series).fillna(0)], axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df2
    customer  product1  product2  product7  product10  product12  product3  product11  product17  product20
0  customer1       2.0       3.0       5.0        1.0        2.0      10.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
1  customer2       1.0       0.0       0.0        2.0        0.0       0.0        3.0        5.0        0.0
2  customer3       0.0       0.0       0.0        0.0        8.0       9.0        2.0        0.0        5.0
```